# Nmap Spoofing NSOCK ERROR

Tags: nmap

I've recently tried out the following nmap command on my Kali Linux virtual machine with Nmap 7.91,

```
nmap -sS -e eth0 -S 12.12.12.12 192.168.0.102
```

I was trying to perform a SYN scan with a spoofed IP of 12.12.12.12 on to my host computer with WireShark on it. Upon doing it I received this error:

```
NSOCK ERROR [0.2750s] mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 192.168.0.105:0 failed (IOD #1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

Yet, checking on my WireShark, the spoofing works. So I'm kinda confused as to what this is.

Comment: Please stick to one question per post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 0 is a reserved port number that serves as a wildcard to tell an underlying OS to search for a free, dynamic port that can be used to establish connections for an application, saving developers the need to hardcode any port number.

So I'm presuming that's why NMAP could not bind its socket connection to PORT 0, but is rather redirected to another dynamic port.

More info: https://www.lifewire.com/port-0-in-tcp-and-udp-818145